# Yammer JSON SDK authenticates through ADFS in Chrome and FF, but Access Denied in IE

Tags: javascript, json, sdk, adfs, yammer

We've started testing out the JSON APi using the JavaScript SDK. We have ADFS set up to authenticate in IE and if you open up a browser window and go to our network on Yammer this all works as does embedding the Yammer feed using the Embed code.

However we are getting an issue with the JSON feed - with all browsers but IE we'll get the login prompt if not already logged in and then this will take us through and we'll see the feed, however in IE we get the pop up of Access Denied.

We've added the assets.yammer.com/assets/platform_js_sdk.js into ADFS as a recognized source

Has anyone else had a problem with Just IE and Authentication through ADFS?

Thanks in advance!
Rich

We have taken the code from the Yammer API reference and are using it as follows:

```
$scope.yammerRequest = function(){
    yam.platform.request({
        url: "messages/in_group/1312007.json?threaded=true",
        //url: "messages.json?threaded=true",
        //url: "messages.json?threaded=true",     //this is one of many REST endpoints that are available
        method: "GET",
        success: function (data) { 
            //Angulars $scope getting lost when inside an external library
            // so we need to find the controller, which we can use to get the $scope
            //get the controller
            var controllerElement = document.querySelector('[ng-controller=YammerFeedCtrl]')
            //use angularjs to get the scope from the controller
            var $scope= angular.element(controllerElement).scope();
            //get the messages from the data
            $scope.yammerfeed = data
            $scope.convertDateStringsToDates($scope.yammerfeed)
                            $scope.loaded = true
            //make sure we apply the changes so they are reflected to the GUI
            $scope.$apply();

        },
        error: function (user) {
            alert("There was an error with the request.");
        }
    });
}
var init = function () {
$scope.selectUser($scope.yammerUsers[0])
    //all Javascript interaction need to be done via thier SDK
    //login to yammer
    //yam.platform.login()
    //yam.connect.loginButton('#yammer-login', function (resp) { if (resp.authResponse) { document.getElementById('yammer-login').innerHTML = 'Welcome to Yammer!'; } }); 
    // url: https://www.yammer.com/oauth2/access_token.json?client_id=[:client_id]&client_secret=[:client_secret]&code=[:code]

    //check login status
    yam.getLoginStatus(
        function(response) {
            if (response.authResponse) {  //if logged in
                //request massages from yammer
                var controllerElement = document.querySelector('[ng-controller=YammerFeedCtrl]')
                //use angularjs to get the scope from the controller
                var $scope= angular.element(controllerElement).scope();
                $scope.yammerRequest();
            }
            else {
                //alert("not logged in")
                //all Javascript interaction need to be done via thier SDK
                //login to yammer
                yam.platform.login(
                    function(response){
                        if (response.authResponse) {
                            //var controllerElement = document.querySelector('[ng-controller=YammerFeedCtrl]')
                            ////use angularjs to get the scope from the controller
                            //var $scope= angular.element(controllerElement).scope();
                            //$scope.yammerRequest();
                            yam.getLoginStatus(
        function(response) {
            if (response.authResponse) {
                            yam.platform.request({
        //url: "messages.json?threaded=true",
        url: "messages/in_group/1312007.json?threaded=true",
        //url: "messages.json?threaded=true",     //this is one of many REST endpoints that are available
        method: "GET",
        success: function (data) { 
            //Angulars $scope getting lost when inside an external library
            // so we need to find the controller, which we can use to get the $scope
            //get the controller
            var controllerElement = document.querySelector('[ng-controller=YammerFeedCtrl]')
            //use angularjs to get the scope from the controller
            var $scope= angular.element(controllerElement).scope();
            //get the messages from the data
            $scope.yammerfeed = data
            $scope.convertDateStringsToDates($scope.yammerfeed)
                $scope.loaded = true            
            //make sure we apply the changes so they are reflected to the GUI
            $scope.$apply();

        },
        error: function (data, data1, data2) {
            alert(data.statusText);
        }
    });
    }
    });
```

Comment: Which version of IE are you testing in?

Comment: Just repo'd this with IE11. I'm looking into it right now.

Comment: Can you confirm that your login pages are in the same security zone as Yammer. We use the popup window to communicate back to the embed iframe, but when the popup window navigates from a trusted site to a non-trusted site this reference is lost.

Comment: Hi Sugeddran - I'm using this on IE10. For the security zone question - are you referring to the set up of zones in ADFS? 

If I log out of Yammer, then go to my demo json feed page - I'll receive the pop up to yammer.com/dialog/authenticate with our client ID, then on entering my email we forward through to our adfs server, then back to https://yammer.com/ournetwork/dialog/oauth?display=popup&client_id= our client ID.

Comment: Update - fired up a VM and added yammer and adfs into the trusted sites in IE11 and was able to authenticate with no issues.

Will now be sharing this with our network admins to compare this with our global policy settings. Will advise if this resolves it.

Comment: Update 2 - we were able to place the domains all within the trusted zones and can now call the JSON feed after adfs authentication. - thanks for your tip Sugendran.

Answer (score 0):

Whoops - forgot to post an answer - update2 has the info on the solution - just need to have everything in the same security zone.

Answer (score 0):

I've been beating my head over this problem for days and you are going to go insane when you see how easy it is to solve. You have to :

1. Open Internet Explorer
2. Press "Alt" key to bring up toolbar
3. Select "Tools"
4. Select "Internet Options"
5. Select the "Security" tab
6. Select "Trusted Sites" then click the "sites" button
7. Add www.yammer.com to zone

That should work. Let me know how it goes.

Comment: That is indeed the solution that @Sugendran proposed in the comments almost a year ago.